# How to save a sequence in an array?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to set the values of r (which is a sequence) in 1D array. So, I can use it further to construct a 2D array. Below written code is giving following error:
**File "V_urc_3D.py", line 28, in 
    r[j] = np.linspace(0.01,lim,500)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.**

Could anyone help to solve this problem.

```html
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D



Mh = np.linspace(10**11, 10**13, 5)
Rv = 259.3*(Mh/10**12)**(1/3)

r = np.zeros(len(Rv))
for j in np.arange(len(Rv)):
 lim = Rv[j]
 r[j] = np.linspace(0.01,lim,500)
```

Comment: Try : `r = np.zeros(len(Rv),500)`.

Answer (score 0):

`r = np.zeros(len(Rv))` creates a numpy array initialised with zeros, which are (by default) floating-point values.

In the line that the error traceback references, you are attempting to assign `np.linspace(0.01, lim, 500)` (which is an array of 500 floating-point values) to a memory location which only has space for a *single* floating-point value; hence the error.

For an immediate fix, add a dimension to the initialisation of `r`, specifically `r = np.zeros(len(Rv), 500)`. If you are interested in more advanced syntax, list comprehension can give you a speed boost:

```
r = np.array([np.linspace(0.01,lim,500) for lim in Rv])
```